# Exposing or not exposing an API

Tags: c, cross-platform

I have the current dilemna in one of my portable C libraries I am working with. I have two high-level lib (say libA and libB). They provide very different API, and depend on user configuration options. I am against merging them together since it would mean merging any later libC, libD with libA. So I am trying to keep this clean separation. This also mean that application programmer can have a lightweight application if they only need libA and not libB.

The issue is that libB uses symbols from libA. However it is using a low level API from libA that I do not want to expose. Is there a way to prevent exposing this low level API while at the same time avoid code duplication ?

I am using the [gcc visibility flags](http://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/Visibility) during compilation on UNIX and the equivalent on windows. So clearly the symbols are visibles:

```
$ nm -D bin/libA.so
[...]
00000000000045e6 T low_level_func1
00000000000043d8 T low_level_func2
```

Would it be possible for me to create a static `low-level` library ? During the build I would link libA & libB against it and never install or distribute this `low-level` library ? 
Is this portable ? I need to find a portable solution (Linux, Windows, FreeBSD, MacOSX...)

Thanks

Comment: `__attribute__((visibility("package")))` is what you're looking for.

Comment: Can't you mix both libraries in one? And you could also add comments like `/* internal utility, do not use */` in low-level headers specific to `libA`

Comment: Why not just make one library? If they always depend on each other they belong together anyway. Now you're just creating a linking mess for no advantage.

Comment: google does not return a single hit for "__attribute__((visibility("package")))". What is this ?

Comment: __attribute__((visibility("..."))) is a keyword understood by gcc to manage visibility. In H2CO3's example, "package" is only an example.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't try to do hacks and workarounds here, it's a design issue and doing workaround will eventually get back to you. You may want to look into the Adapter design pattern: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern